# Internet connection only avaiable if started manually

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet

Every time Linux boots I have to manually use the following two commands in order to have a working internet connection.

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full 

dhclient eth0
```

I am looking for a method so the internet connection will start automatically when Lubuntu boots up.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
allow-hotplug eth0

#iface wlan0 inet manual
#wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
xrandr -s 960x540
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill block wifi
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
ip link set eth0 up
ifup eth0
dhcpcd eth0

exit 0
```

---

```
systemctl status rc-local: 
globalisation@WindowsXP:~$ systemctl status rc-local
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: 
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-04 00:31:28 CEST; 15min 
  Process: 636 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 04 00:31:27 WindowsXP systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Jun 04 00:31:28 WindowsXP rc.local[636]: Can't open display
Jun 04 00:31:28 WindowsXP systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, 
Jun 04 00:31:28 WindowsXP systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibilit
Jun 04 00:31:28 WindowsXP systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Unit entered failed stat
Jun 04 00:31:28 WindowsXP systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit

globalisation@WindowsXP:~$
```

When Lubuntu boots it appears these errors:

```
Failed to start LSB: IPV4 DHCP client with IPV4ALL support. 
See 'systemctl status dhcpcd.service' for details 
16.780656 usb 1-1.4.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

`/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase
#

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable Spoof protection (reverse-path filter)
# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to
# prevent some spoofing attacks
#net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

---

It also seems that the second command `dhclient eth0` after using the MANDATORY ONE `ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full` (still all the commands take effects only manually) could be replaced with  `ifup eth0` in order for the internet to work.

Maybe an important part of the next log is `Link detected: no` After boot if immediately the first command is `ethtool eth0` the output is:

```
:~$ sudo ethtool eth0
[sudo] password for globalisation: 
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no
```

I would like to add that the same Linux machine in discussion always receives internet connection instantly/directly, even after reboot, shutdown, with no others supplementary manual commands, or any other actions, if I only change the cable from "the problematic in discussion internet connection" to the "non-problematic" completely different DSL router connection(another ISP, BUT STILL THE SAME ETHERNET CABLE)

The problematic connection dependent on the manual commands "in discussion" which has the internet only after the manually commands, is from another ISP and is a coaxial/tv cable modem.

Could it be problems with onboard NIC?

This exactly same machine with this exactly system with  "in discussion", THE SAME ETHERNET CABLE, takes/keeps internet directly/immediately even after reboot/shutdown or whatever I would do, without any manual commands, ONLY MOVING THE ETHERNET CABLE from this "in discussion" problematic router to another router connected to completely another internet connection on another ISP.

The same port on the router the same cable, even from in discussion PROBLEMATIC ROUTER  also Windows 7 and Windows 10 connect to the internet instantly/directly without any clicks supplementary clicks, only changing the cable from the Linux machine to the Windows machine.

If you have please any ideas how this could happen, I have just remembered that  this in discussion same machine + same OS(Linux no changed configurations) + same Ethernet cable always "received and kept"  the internet automatically (no extra manual commands) from all the 3 different models of routers.

All 3 connections and routers were from the same ISP, other than this forth problematic connection and router.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the final result, in order to have internet access automatically after reboot/shutdown/sleep with no more manual commands:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    pre-up ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full

allow-hotplug eth0
```

/etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 70 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill block wifi
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
ip link set eth0 up

exit 0
```